# Why can't I use a filename containing a space with playsound in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, playsound, python-playsound

If I use a music file name `sample.mp3`, it works, but if I use `sample one.mp3`, it doesn't work.
Even if I insert a desktop pathway, it stops working, and if I save the same file in other folders and insert its pathway, it starts working.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('play me.mp3')
```

Comment: What does *"it doesn't work"* mean? Do you get any output, errors, or tracebacks? If so, please [edit] your question and post their *full text* as formatted text, not images.

Comment: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/40#issuecomment-674285344

Answer (score 0):

spaces in filenames aren't supported on playsound. instead, format the string path to replace spaces like so

```py
from playsound import playsound
path_to_play = "play me.mp3"
path_to_play = path_to_play.replace(" ", "%20")
playsound(path_to_play)
```

solution from https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/40#issuecomment-674285344

spaces in file names is recommended to be avoided, so it might be better just to rename those files to use underscores instead of spaces

```py
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        os.rename(filename, filename.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Comment: sir, it's not working.
please help

Comment: are spaces in file names a required format? if not, have a script to replace those filename spaces with an underscore